# Filling array with objects

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class called Person which is like the following:

```
public class Person
{
    public static String name;
    public static int regNumber;

    public   String getName() {
       return name;
    }

    public  int getRegNumber() {
       return regNumber;
    }

    public Person(int x) {

       this.name = n;
       this.regNumber = x;
    }
}
```

I use this class to fill an array with students:

```
public class PeopleArray
{
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Person [] students = new Person[3];
        int reg = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i<students.length; i++) {

           students[i] = new Person(reg++);

        }

        for (Person stu: students) {
           System.out.println(stu.getRegNumber());
        }

     }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to print out the ages of each individual person it seem that the array was filled with only the last object created by the Person class, because the only number that is printed is the number 2.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the `static` modifier from your fields. And look up its meaning.

Comment: This compiles? What about `this.name = n;` ?

Answer (score 5):

The fields `name` and `regNumber` are `static`, which means they do not belong to any particular instance, but rather to the class as a whole. All you need to do is remove the `static` keyword from the field declarations in `Person`, making them *instance variables* instead of *class variables*.

I also suggest you read [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try re-reading your `Person` field declaration:

```
public static String name;
public static int regNumber;
```

You have used `static` members, if you remove this keyword, it should start working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `static` from the Your `instance variables`. if you used `static` in `instance variables` then last modified value is present in the name and regNumber.

```
public class Person{
    public String name;
    public int regNumber;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor in Person class  assign a variable 'n' to the name. But you haven't defined it anywhere. 
Other than that, remove 'static' keyword from your variables.